# Get image from list view

Tags: c#, listview

Is it possible to derive the image clicked in a listview control if this is how its setup?

```
imageListLarge.Images.Add(Bitmap.FromFile("C:\\MyLargeImage1.bmp"));
imageListLarge.Images.Add(Bitmap.FromFile("C:\\MyLargeImage2.bmp"));

//Assign the ImageList objects to the ListView.
listView1.LargeImageList = imageListLarge;
```

If i could get the image type then i would no how to handle the following steps.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add a tag property for each listview item of image array item.

Comment: you cant use tag - http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/115832/imagelist-does-not-preserve-the-tag-property-of-images-added